# Is this vector space complete?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is the space $L^\infty(X, L^2(Y))$ complete for $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $X$ and $Y$? What about $L^\infty(X, B)$ for an arbitrary Banach space $B$?

Edit: I think it is complete and it seems to me that the usual proof where you replace all the absolute values with Banach space norms works (except for perhaps a usage of the dominated convergence theorem somewhere?). Am I correct in that it is complete or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Any thoughts? $\ $

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{gae}[1]{\newcommand{#1}{\operatorname{#1}}}\gae{ess}$Let $S$ be a non-empty set, $E$ be a normed space and $Bd(S,E)=\{f:S\to E\,:\, \sup_{s\in S}\lVert f(s)\rVert<\infty\}$ be the set of bounded functions from $S$ to $E$ endowed with the norm $\lVert f\rVert_\infty=\sup_{s\in S}\lVert f(s)\rVert$ - not to be confused with the $\infty$-norm of $L^\infty$, which is $\ess\sup \lVert f\rVert$.

It's elementary to prove that $Bd(S,E)$ is Banach if and only if $E$ is Banach.

In your setting, consider the "tautological" linear map \begin{align}T:Bd(X,B)&\to L^\infty(X,B)\\ f&\mapsto f\end{align}

$T$ is surjective and it satisfies $\lVert T\rVert=1$.
Finally, let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $L^\infty(X,B)$. I claim that there is a Cauchy sequence in $f_n\in Bd(X,B)$ such that $Tf_n=x_n$. If that's the case, then there will be some $f\in Bd(X,B)$ such that $f_n\to f$, and therefore $x_n\to Tf$.

On to the proof, consider $y_n$ some functions $y_n:X\to B$ such that $y_n$ is a representative of $x_n$. Since $\ess\sup$ of a real-valued function is (also) the least essential upper bound, consider the sets $A_n=\{x\in X\,:\, \lVert y_n(x)\rVert>\lVert x_n\rVert_\infty\}$ and $B_{n,m}=\{x\in X\,:\, \lVert y_n(x)-y_m(x)\rVert>\lVert x_n-y_m\rVert_\infty\}$. These sets have all measure $0$ in $X$. Then, call $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}y_n(x)&\text{if }x\notin\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}A_k\cup\bigcup_{i,j\in\Bbb N}B_{i,j}\\ 0&\text{if }x\notin\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}A_k\cup\bigcup_{i,j\in\Bbb N}B_{i,j}\end{cases}$$

It is clear that $f_n\in Bd(X,B)$, that $Tf_n=x_n$ and that $\lVert f_n-f_m\rVert_\infty=\lVert x_n-x_m\rVert_\infty$. The latter implies that $f_n$ is Cauchy.